# Lombok is not generating code through Maven

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I am working on a small jar lib and am encountering a problem with Lombok that I have not had previously. For some reason, lombok is not generating code during the Maven build.

To be clear, this is not an IDE problem. I am using Intellij 14 and have the Lombok plugin configured. Intellij runs fine and the Intellij compiler even works with my unit tests.

When I run a full Maven install (from either Intellij or the command line), I get errors in my unit tests around the methods generated by Lombok. If I decompile the `.class` files, the code is missing.

So a simple class like:

```
   @Data
   @Builder
   @AllArgsConstructor
   @NoArgsConstructor
   public class PhoneNumber {
       public String areaCode;
       public String prefix;
       public String number;

       [... a couple of simple hand-written methods...]
   }
```

Generates code that looks like this, when decompiled:

```
> javap.exe PhoneNumber.class 

Compiled from "PhoneNumber.java"
public class com.example.PhoneNumber {
  public java.lang.String areaCode;
  public java.lang.String prefix;
  public java.lang.String number;
  public com.example.PhoneNumber();
  [... a couple of simple hand-written methods...]
}
```

No methods are generated and the unit tests fail.

The entries in `pom.xml` seem normal enough:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.16.6</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an incompatibility with the `maven-compiler-plugin` version. I confirm that lombok annotations are not processed with the `pom.xml` you are using. But everything builds fine if you use the most recent version.

```
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.3</version>
```

Comment: That was absolutely the problem. Thank you very, very much.